# Multiline string for TextFormString validator

Tags: dart, flutter

In my `TextFormString` for Password Field I have `validator` that returns a String. The problem is this `String` is too long and it doesn't fit the screen.

I'd like to make it multiline, but I can't find how to do it: I've tried setting width for the `Container` this `TextFormString` is in -- no effect, I've hardcoded newlines `\n` to my String, it actually worked but I think there must be some other solution to break it to lines more dynamically.

What is the right way to do it?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdfYI.png)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can decorate your `TextFormFiled` so that the error label has more than 1 lines:

```
errorMaxLines: 2
```

Here an example:

```
TextFormField(
    decoration: const InputDecoration(
    icon: Icon(Icons.person),
    hintText: 'What do people call you?',
    labelText: 'Name *',
    errorMaxLines: 2
    ),
    validator: (String value) {
    return value.contains('@')
        ? 'Do not use the @ char. Do not use the @ char. Do not use the @ char. Do not use the @ char.'
        : null;
    },
),
```

[image]

In this example I didn't set `obscureText: true` (desiderata for a password field), so that the text is visible.

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks a lot!

Comment: what if the error message is dynamic, meaning we are unsure about the error message length?

Answer (score -1):

I think the accepted answer is deprecated. Now you can add the `errorMaxLines` in `InputDecoration` like this

```
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    errorMaxLines: 2,
  ),
  validator: (value) {
    if (value.isEmpty) {
      return 'Please Enter Something';
    }
    return null;
  },
)
```